# How to set Apache 2 to use the correct PHP version

Tags: apache-http-server, php5

I have Apache 2 installed in CentOS 6.7 and multiple PHP versions (it came with version 5.5).

I have installed PHP 5.5 using YUM, but even when I see the PHP version is correctly installed by issuing "php -v" command, version reported by phpinfo() is incorrect. It shows the old one.

How can I set Apache2 to use the correct version?

Comment: You'll find some good suggestions here: http://serverfault.com/questions/428800/how-do-i-tell-apache-which-php-to-use

Comment: Where is your php coming from?  rpm -qf $(which php)

Comment: What all php packages do you have installed?    rpm -qa | grep php